# C# ComboBox SelectedIndex is always at 0 once Items are added

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, selectedindex

**EDIT** This has nothing to do with SelectedIndex property... If the default combobox text is "ABCD" and there's an item that starts with "ABCD", the combobox will find that item and select it.
How do I prevent that from happening?

**Original**

When I click `ComboBox1` (Windows Forms - Visual Studio), the system will search the database for information to insert into a `ComboBox` (`string[,] Intel` is where this information is stored). Before the `Click` event is called, the `ComboBox` is with `SelectedIndex = -1`. This is how it adds Intel into this specific combobox:

```
for (int Dim1 = 0; Dim1 < Intel.GetLength(0); Dim1++)
{
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(Intel[Dim1, 1]);
}
```

My problem is: Once I add the first item, `ComboBox1.SelectedIndex` is set to `0`. Even if I use `ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;`, it still assumes it as `0`. Same with `ComboBox1.SelectedValue = null;` or `ComboBox1.Text = null;`. By `TextBox1.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex;`, `TextBox1.Text` will display `-1`.

I've done this with another ComboBox, and it works... It does set the selectedindex at -1, and the user will see the default text I want, which is not included in the items - and it can't. So, I'm thinking this must be some property I've set wrong.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449915/how-to-add-empty-or-custom-value-to-a-bound-combobox

Comment: are you setting the `DataSource` property of the combobox? that could cause this issue.  `You cannot set the SelectedIndex of a ComboBox item to -1 if the item is a data-bound item.` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Change of plans. Check question again... Such a simple thing.... How do I prevent the combobox from selecting an item that relates to the Text value?

Comment: you should show your combobox configuration i.e. "default text"  and also anywhere where you might be preselecting an option

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#remarks

To deselect the currently selected item, set the SelectedIndex to -1. You cannot set the SelectedIndex of a ComboBox item to -1 if the item is a data-bound item.

[See this image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qly9E.png)